# A word to refer to both offers and bids

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Offer: when someone offers to sell something
Bid: when someone offers to buy something

So both offers and bids are in fact "offers". But I am looking for a word that cannot be confusing with the specific meaning of offer.
May be a market action, or something.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence showing how you want to use the term, and describe what sort of context it applies to.

Comment: Mostly, we try to keep the two ideas as completely separate as possible. Here's how GSA does it.  http://www.acq.osd.mil/dpap/ccap/cc/corhb/Files/Forms/SF%2033%20-%20Solicitation%20Offer%20and%20Award.pdf

Comment: No, offers and bids are not the same at all but context is crucial in any case.

Comment: The standard term in finance is ***quotes***, as in *quoting a price* or the famous duo *trades and quotes*. If this is a finance application, you must call this category *quotes* or nobody will understand you. Don't name it anything else.

Answer (score 2):

In finance, to avoid ciponfusion, the term are ***[bid and ask](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Ask):***

***Ask***:

> - The ask price (a shortening of asked price) is the price at which a market maker or broker offers to sell a security or commodity.
>     The price another market maker or broker is willing to pay for that security is called the bid price, and the difference between the two prices is called the spread.
> - ***Bid and ask*** prices are typically reported to the media for commodities and over-the-counter (OTC) transactions. In contrast, last, or closing, prices are reported for exchange-traded and national market securities.

(Dictionary of Financial Terms)